# Why does my Code Igniter routes not route the way I intended?

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, xampp

I just started learning about Code Igniter using XAMPP, but for some reason, my routes only work with the default 'welcome'.

If I change it, I always provoke a 404 not found

For example:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

works fine if my controller is named Welcome.php.

But if I make a new one, or change the name into other like Page.php, Home.php etc. and change the code into:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'page';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

it always summons a 404 not found. Is there any fix or work around for this?

I wanted to change the controller Welcome.php into something I like, for example Home.php, Dashboard.php, Admin.php etc.

Comment: for example, if you copy the welcome.php controller file and name it main.php then set  $route['default_controller'] = 'main'; it will look for that main.php controller file. then inside that controller file, the default index view page (the user sees) would be called.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)! It seems a question identical to yours has been asked before. Please relate to existing material and otherwise clarify in your question in which regard it is different.